# Como obter o total de marcador (marker) no google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou usando [Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). Aqui está o código:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

                    //Obter lat long do marcador
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });
                    lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                    long = marker.getPosition().lng();
                    markers.push(marker);

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
```

Quando usuário digitar nome errado sem querer, pode mostrar vários marcadores no google maps.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o marcador for maior que 1, mostrar aviso e limpar google maps para fazer pesquisa novamente.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Os seus marcadores estão no Array markers, logo, é só você verificar o tamanho desse Array com o length, ficando assim: if (markers.length > 1) { //.... faça algo }.

Comment: Sim, cada 1 marcador, ele criar 2 no array. Se ele achar 3 marcadores, ele fica com 6 no array. Isso não é estranho ?

Comment: Dentro do seu `places.forEach`, observe que você está criando dois objetos de Marker, ou seja, a cada iteração no _forEach_, cria-se dois objetos no Array. Eu não sei o porque você precisa assim, pois se for apenas para pegar a lat/lng do marcador, isso não é necessário. Portanto, dessa forma está duplicando o seu Array final.

Comment: O problema estava na linha `markers.push(marker);`, eu preciso pegar lat e long do marcador.

Comment: Agora ficou fácil como você disse, verificar Array markers.

Comment: Beleza então, vou colocar como resposta. Só marcar como correta, fazendo favor.

Comment: @DouglasGarrido, demoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme eu havia comentado, você já corrigiu a necessidade de criar dois objetos Marker no Array.

Após isso, você consegue verificar a quantidade de marcadores na variável `markers` utilizando a propriedade `length`, ficando assim:

```
if (markers.length > 1) {
    //.... faça algo aqui
}
```